# What does csr_matrix.sort_indices do?

Tags: python, sorting, sparse-matrix

I make a csr_matrix in the following way:

```
>>> A = sparse.csr_matrix([[0, 1, 0],
                           [1, 0, 1],
                           [0, 1, 0]])
>>> A[2,:] = np.array([-1, -2, -3])

>>> A.indptr
Out[12]: array([0, 1, 3, 6], dtype=int32)
>>> A.indices
Out[13]: array([1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1], dtype=int32)
>>> A.data
Out[14]: array([ 1,  1,  1, -1, -3, -2], dtype=int64)
```

Now I want to interchange the last two elements in the `indices` and `data` arrays, so I try:

```
>>> A.sort_indices()
```

This does not do anything to my matrix however. The [manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sort_indices.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.sort_indices) for this function only states that it sorts the indices.

1. What does this function do? In which condition can you see a difference?
2. How can I sort the `indices` and `data` arrays, such that for each row the indices are sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the document, `A.sort_indices()` sorts the indices in-place. But there is a cache: [if `A.has_sorted_indices` is True, it won't do anything](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/233c0ce63910f4eba6c31d95fa2a42ea0ac86e5b/scipy/sparse/compressed.py#L1033-L1040) (the cache was [introduced at 0.7.0](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/0f092cd973826ddc9b1dad93f891e4fbffa48e8e)).

So, in order to see a difference, you need to manually set `A.has_sorted_indices` to False.

```
>>> A.has_sorted_indices, A.indices
(True, array([1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1], dtype=int32))
>>> A.sort_indices()
>>> A.has_sorted_indices, A.indices
(True, array([1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1], dtype=int32))
>>> A.has_sorted_indices = False
>>> A.sort_indices()
>>> A.has_sorted_indices, A.indices
(True, array([1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Note that, unlike what OP has indicated, as of SciPy 0.19.0 running `A[2, :] = [-1, -2, -3]` no longer produces an out-of-order index ([this should have been fixed in 0.14.0](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3233)). On the other hand, this operation produces a warning:

> SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a `csr_matrix` is expensive. `lil_matrix` is more efficient.

Anyway, we could easily produce out-of-order index in other ways, e.g. by matrix multiplication:

```
>>> B = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
>>> C = B*B
>>> C.has_sorted_indices, C.indices
(0, array([2, 0, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int32))
>>> C.sort_indices()
>>> C.has_sorted_indices, C.indices
(True, array([0, 2, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
```